# Limit cipher suites for NSURLSession

Tags: ios, macos, security, nsurlsession

I need customized set of cipher suites for Mac and iOS application.
When I'm using sockets directly there is an API to control cipher suites: `SSLSetEnabledCiphers`.

Now `NSRURLSession` doesn't provide API to control that. Some time ago I was able to find some instruction how to do it using `Info.plist` file. Now I can't find it.
I don't remember details, but I'm sure since Apple introduced ATS it is possible to define list of cipher suites used by `NSURLSession`.

My list of ciphers can be generated like this:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!ADH:!EXP:!MD5:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-SSLv3'
```

And for socket when using `SSLSetEnabledCiphers` it looks like this:

```
static const SSLCipherSuite ENABLED_CIPHER_SUITES[] = {
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
    TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
    TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
};
```

Comment: NSURL and the underlying NSSession (or maybe it was the NSSocket) are pretty lame. You can't do things like set protocol versions (say, TLS 1.0 and above), or set cipher suites (like AES-GCM). I filed a Apple bug (RADAR) for it years ago. I no longer have the iTunes account to look up the RADAR number.

Comment: there is API for minium TLS version and it works (I've wrote automated test for it against openssl command line tool).